# What is the best word for a menu item on a website for a page that shows how to get to the company offices?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

On a company website one usually has a page which tells customers how to get to the company offices.

In German, the word for this menu tab is "Anreise" but both standard translations sound odd in English:

- Arrival
- Journey

What is a one-word menu title for such a menu item? The only one I can think of is:

- Location

What is the best English translation in this context for *Anreise*?

Comment: Have you looked around the (English-speaking) 'net and seen what others are doing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because each word request needs to be set in a textual context (a sentence or a paragraph). Requests for free-floating terms used for menu items, variable names and the like are considered off-topic on EL&U. Please [edit] your question to supply a suitable textual context for the word you are requesting.

Comment: @Lawrence - Interesting.  Are you suggesting that words can only be discussed on ELU if they are part of a sentence or paragraph?

Comment: I see you’ve asked the question on [Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11831/142322), so I’ll answer your comment there.

Comment: This question is not about "what is a word I can use in a programming context?", and more "what word is commonly used on english speaking websites?". To me, it differs significantly from the "name this variable" questions we close. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're wanting just one word either ***Directions*** or ***Location*** could serve.

Answer (score 5):

On the vast majority of business websites, this information doesn't have a standalone part of the website, instead it's part of the "**Contact us**" or "**Contact**" section.

However, when the company is some sort of an attraction (such as a museum or a hotel), in my experience the page is often called "**Getting here**". Examples from a quick search that I've found are [Warner Bros Tour, London](https://www.wbstudiotour.co.uk/getting-here) and [The British Museum, London](https://www.britishmuseum.org/visiting/getting_here.aspx).

*NB This may be more applicable to British English than American English. I haven't been on many US attraction websites in order to know.*